# Android "Hello World" issue

Tags: android, adt

this is the code i have written

```
package com.test.AndroidApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android....");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

And i am getting these errors

```
[2010-04-06 19:24:03 - Emulator] 2010-04-07 00:49:03.366 emulator[498:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2010-04-06 19:34:42 - TestApp] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.test.AndroidApp.TestAppActivity activity launch'!
```

I have the latest sdk and ADT installed.

What is the solution ????

Thanks

Comment: WHat platform are you using? Also what is the target framwework set as in the emulator? (1.6 etc..)

Comment: I am using Mac OS , with Eclipse Galileo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSQuickdraw warning occurs on emulators running on Macs I believe. However it does not error out the emulator. I've run a machine with this warning for months and it hasn't been a problem. The disconnect error is usually a timeout issue connecting to the emulator I believe, but don't get to distracted with the first warning.

Answer (score 1):

It should work though this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=724)